# Holt function error

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, holtwinters

I want to use holt() function on R, and apply it on a time series ts. But I get this error and don't understand why:

> holt(timeseries)

Error in etsTargetFunctionInit(par = par, y = y, nstate = nstate, errortype = errortype,  : 
  Not compatible with requested type: [type=character; target=double].
In addition: Warning message:
In is.constant(y) : NAs introduced by coercion

I get the same error when I try other forecasting functions like thetaf and ses.

Answer (score 1):

The error message suggests that it expects a numerical vector, but you are providing a character vector.

Check the class of your `timeseries`.